# How do I index an image in FFmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I would like to convert a 16bit image into an indexed one, using the command line interface with FFmpeg.

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow, this site helps you to fix a specific issue with your provided code. If you want to know how to use a specific utility, please read its help and usage information/man page.

Comment: If an 8-bit palette is sufficient, check out palettegen/paletteuse.  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen-1  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse